# When I do an ajax request i get back the responseText and debugbar info (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, phpdebugbar

When I do an ajax request i get back the responseText and debugbar info (Laravel)

I get something like that:

```html
ok<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' property='stylesheet' href='//127.0.0.1:8000/_debugbar/assets/stylesheets?v=1674820783&theme=auto' data-turbolinks-eval='false' data-turbo-eval='false'><script src='//127.0.0.1:8000/_debugbar/assets/javascript?v=1674820783' data-turbolinks-eval='false' data-turbo-eval='false'></script><script data-turbo-eval="false">jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb, false); }; refStyle.innerHTML = '.phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-compact, .sf-dump-str-collapse .sf-dump-str-collapse, .sf-dump-str-expand .sf-dump-str-expand { display: none; }'; (doc.documentElement.firstElementChild || doc.documentElement.children[0]).appendChild(refStyle); refStyle = doc.createElement('style'); (doc.documentElement.firstElementChild || doc.documentElement.children[0]).appendChild(refStyle); if (!doc.addEventListener) { addEventListener = function (element, eventName, callback) { element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function (e) { e.preventDefault
```

How can i prevent sendig debug bar info?

Comment: I get this from debugbar, i dont know why stack changed it <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' property='stylesheet' href='//127.0.0.1:8000/_debugbar/assets/stylesheets?v=1674820783&theme=auto' data-turbolinks-eval='false' data-turbo-eval='false'><script src='//127.0.0.1:8000/_debugbar/assets/javascript?v=1674820783' data-turbolinks-eval='false' data-turbo-eval='false'></script><script data-turbo-eval="false">jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc =

Comment: The response is generated because you used dd() function anywhere in the Laravel application. Share the controller file code that is handling the request so that a specific solution can be given.

Comment: I added a answer with the controller file

Answer (score 0):

This are the few controller functions that I call by ajax request.

The function getusers that show me all users on a crud its the one thath first braks my program

public function usersCrudView(){

```
        if (session('rol')=='admin'){

            return view("crudUsers");
        }
    }


    public  function getusers(){
        if (session('rol')=='admin'){

            $users=DB::table('users')
                ->orderByRaw('email_verified_at IS NULL DESC')
                ->orderBy('email_verified_at', 'asc')
                ->get();
            return $users->toJson();
        }
    }

    public function verificado(){
        try {
            if ($_GET['status']=="verify"){
                User::verificarEmail($_GET['id']);
                return "ok";
            }else if ($_GET['status']=="no-verify") {
                User::denegarEmail($_GET['id']);
                return "ok";
            }else if ($_GET['status']=="ban"){
                User::banearEmail($_GET['id']);
                return "ok";
                return "ok";
            }else if ($_GET['status']=='quitar_ban') {
                User::quitarBan($_GET['id']);
                return "ok";
            }else if($_GET['status']=='quitar_denegado'){
                User::quitarDenegado($_GET['id']);
                return "ok";

            }

            return "no";
        }catch (\Exception $e){
            return "no";
        }



    }
```